# Error in creating a simple workbook using Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi, xls, excel

i am trying to create a simple workbook using Apache POI and getting the following errors.Using apchhe poi 3.9 kindly help me to get out of this thanks.

Errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlException
    at xlscreate.xlsclass.main(xlsclass.java:24)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
```

CODE:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import java.io.InputStream;






public class xlsclass {

     public static void main(String[] args)  throws Exception,Throwable{

           // Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
           // FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("workbook.xls");
           // wb.write(fileOut);
           // fileOut.close();

            Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("c:/workbook.xlsx");
            wb.write(fileOut);
            fileOut.close();


     }
}
```

Comment: Have you imported org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException? I don't see this in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache POI has dependencies. You need to look them up and add them to your classpath. One of those dependency libraries contains this exception class: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException. Not sure which one. After that the other answers contain hint's for the actual bug in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Apache POI has [a number of dependencies](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components). The full list of the dependencies for each part of Apache POI [are given on the website](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components)

If you use Maven as your build tool, it'll automatically suck down the dependencies when you define your code as depending on Apache POI (that's all defined). If you use Eclipse or Ant, then you should [download](http://poi.apache.org/download.html) the Binary (-bin-) package of Apache POI, and you'll then find all the dependencies in there ready to go.

(For your specific error, you're missing xmlbeans jar, but I suspect you could also be missing some other things to and that's the first one hit)